# Yii CDbCriteria adding unwanted alias

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I need to run following statements by [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) in Yii :

```
SELECT `tbl_products`.`id` FROM `tbl_products`
INNER JOIN `tbl_producttags` 
    ON `tbl_products`.`id` = `tbl_producttags`.`product_id` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_tags`
    ON `tbl_producttags`.`tag_id` = `tbl_tags`.`id`
```

**What I've tried so far :**

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select= '`tbl_products`.`id`';
    $criteria->join ='INNER JOIN `tbl_producttags` ON `tbl_products`.`id` = `tbl_producttags`.`product_id`'
                   . ' INNER JOIN `tbl_tags` ON `tbl_producttags`.`tag_id` = `tbl_tags`.`id`';      
    $products = Products::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But it get me following error :

> SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'tbl_products.id' in 'field list'. The SQL statement executed was:
>   SELECT `tbl_products`.`id` FROM `tbl_products` `t` INNER JOIN
>   `tbl_producttags` ON `tbl_products`.`id` =
>   `tbl_producttags`.`product_id` INNER JOIN `tbl_tags` ON
>   `tbl_producttags`.`tag_id` = `tbl_tags`.`id`

**The problem is :**

It's because of that CDbCriteria added unwanted alias name `t` after `tbl_products`

How can I fix it?

Comment: You not selected tbl_products tablele in your join but

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select= '`yourAlias`.`id`';
    $criteria->alias="yourAlias";
    $criteria->join ='INNER JOIN `tbl_producttags` ON `tbl_products`.`id` = `tbl_producttags`.`product_id`'
                   . ' INNER JOIN `tbl_tags` ON `tbl_producttags`.`tag_id` = `tbl_tags`.`id`';      
    $products = Products::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

the alias name of the table. If not set, it means the alias is 't'

Comment: Can I delete this `t` alias at all?

Comment: you can set this 'alias' => $this->tableName(), but you cant delete alias